# Disable list item Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to disable list item based on condition please help me in this.
In this i want to disable List2 if disable = true.

Html

- {{List1}}
- {{List 2}}

typescript
disable = true;

Comment: You want to disable a list item, ie `<li>something</li>`? Unless there's more code to it, there's nothing to disable there. You can make it look disabled by using some CSS if that's what you're after.
Ideally though, provide some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` attribute cannot be set on a list or a list item, it can only be used on the following HTML tags:

```
<button>    
<fieldset>  
<input> 
<keygen>    
<optgroup>  
<option>    
<select>    
<textarea>
```

for your specific case, you can use this:

**html**

```html
<li [class.disabled]="disabled"> something</li>
```

**css:**

```css
li.disabled{
 cursor: not-allowed;
 opacity: .7;
}
```